# Discord.Py: CommandOnCooldown raise CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)

Tags: python, discord.py

How to stop people from spamming clear command
This is my code but i get this error

> `raise CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)`

```
async def on_command_error(ctx , error):
        if isinstance(error , commands.CommandNotFound):
                pass
        elif isinstance(error , commands.CommandOnCooldown):
                msg = "**Still on cooldown** , please try again in %.2f 's." % error.retry_after
                await ctx.send(msg)
```

And this is my function

```
@client.command(name = 'clear')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
@commands.cooldown(1 , 20 , commands.BucketType.user)
async def clear(ctx , count):
        count = int(count)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = count + 1)
        await ctx.send(f'>>> {count} Messages deleted' , delete_after = 5)
```

Comment: Do you want to print out the seconds someone has to wait? Also: Why do you use `ctx.send?` but never set it as an argument?

Comment: @Dominik Yes i want to show him , I set ctx in on_command_error , It isnt true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one small error here, otherwise the code is correct. The cooldown error simply uses the string that `discord.py` uses for the `commands.CommandOnCooldown` object.
There is also no need to first define a message, simply include everything in `ctx.send("YourText")`.

**Your new event could look like this:**

```py
@client.event / @bot.event / @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        pass

    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"**This command is on cooldown for another " + str("%.2f" % error.retry_after) + " seconds!**") # New time string
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I get the same error again ,
I didnt import anything Do I have to import anything to do this?

Comment: No, but did you make a `listener`/`event` out of your `on_command_error` function?

Comment: I dont have any `@client.event` above `on_command_error`
But on top of this function I have two other functions that I put on top of the first one

Comment: That is your mistake. This has to be an `event`

Comment: Yes it worked tnx but why sometimes you shouldnt have `event` on top of your function if you use you get error , some events need , some dont need = and you need use your `event` Above the function that is above the current function that hasent problem with `event` , sry for my bad english

Comment: The function I gave you can stand wherever you want to have it as it is an event. Actual functions that are custom made/don’t display an actual event have to stand above a command in order to use it.